# How to format following bash/sh/shell date

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh

> How to format this "May 18, 2016 at 1:05:30 PM EDT"  to +%Y-%m-%d
>   00:00:00
>
> ```
> JayOSX:~ jay$ d=$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.someapp.some.plist LastUpdated)
> ```
>
> echo"$d "
>
> ```
> ##returns
> May 18, 2016 at 1:05:30 PM EDT
> ```
>
> I tried:
>
> ```
> date -j -f "%b %d, %Y at %l:%M:S %Z" "$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.someapp.some.plist LastUpdated)” + "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"
> ```

And I got the Following Error:

```
Failed conversion of ``%d,'' using format ``“%b''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: The quote in what you tried, `“`, are these the quotes you really used? Notice the difference: yours: `“`, correct quotes: `"`

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. I used the correct quotes when I ran it on my actual environment.

Comment: @jay You've edited the question so that the reported error will no longer occur. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: No, it still occurs.

Comment: is it okay to use awk to do that?

Comment: sure, how would you go about it, using awk

Comment: @NullSoulException if you have a solution to this can you post it. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go ,

create the infile.txt :

```
echo "May 18, 2016 at 1:05:30 PM EDT" > infile
```

now we have :

```
[za]$ cat infile.txt 
May 18, 2016 at 1:05:30 PM EDT
```

One liner that will do it . FYI,     `"%s-%s-%s %s  %s:%s:%s  \n", $4 , $1 , $2 , $3  , $6 , $7 , $8` is what does the reformatting.

```
 [za]$ awk -F'[ "\t" :,]' '{printf "%s-%s-%s %s  %s:%s:%s  \n", $4 , $1 , $2 , $3  , $6 , $7 , $8  }' infile.txt
```

Outputs :

```
 2016-May-18   1:05:30
```

Quick test .

```
echo May 18, 2016 at 1:05:30 PM EDT | awk -F'[ "\t" :,]' '{printf "%s-%s-%s %s  %s:%s:%s  \n", $4 , $1 , $2 , $3  , $6 , $7 , $8  }'
```

I hope this will help ;).

Comment: definitely helps, but I need it the output to be "2016-05-18 00:00:00"

Comment: hi , on my mac , it prints "05" and not May .  d=$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.someapp.some.plist LastUpdated) 
2016-05-19 15:19:57.548 defaults[11384:186690] ... so , check how you can make the source output the right format.